# Текст в стиле "выделенный мышью"

Tags: html, css

Товарищи, подскажите способ, который можно применить к тексту так, что будет казаться, будто текст выделен мышью.

Игрался с дисплеями, но чёт не выходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: #3390ff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
Все тронулись и, пропуская друг друга в дверях, вышли в коридор и из коридора в залу 
заседания. <span class="highlight">Старшой подошел и сердито ткнул Маслову в плечо
и, кивнув ей головой,</span> повел её в женский коридор. В женском коридоре её всю
ощупали, обыскали и, не найдя ничего (коробка папирос была засунута в калаче),
впустили в ту же камеру, из которой она вышла утром. Солнце спустилось уже за только 
что распустившиеся липы, и комары роями влетали в горницу и жалили Нехлюдова.
```

Comment: А чтобы весь абзац так? все строчки спанами что ле?

Comment: Зачем все строчки? Просто весь абзац заключить в тег, span или p, кусок я просто для наглядности выделил